# Location Manager interrupting GMSMapView

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, gmsmapview

I am facing a very unusual issue. Location manager is interrupting in GMSMapView functions. GMSCamera moves perfect when i comment my Location Manager init code. But when i uncomment location manager code this code doesn't moves the camera position.

I've tried this code

```
 let cameraPostition = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude:
 kUserLatitude, longitude: kUserLongitude, zoom: 10.0) 

 mapView.animate(to: cameraPostition)
```

and this also

```
 mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: kUserLatitude,
 longitude: kUserLongitude, zoom: 10.0)
```

but all in vein. Even i've tried

```
 locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
```

Help in getting through this issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up my problem, by editing my scheme and unchecking "Allow location Simulation"
Hope it may help anyone wandering around :)

[image]